# Simple HTML / CSS Dropdown NavBar not showing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm a beginner in the world of coding and I'm making a drop-down menu in my navbar and it's just not showing, I can actually click the first link in the drop-down menu on only a couple pixels, as if it's there but something's stopping from being seen:

Css:

```css
li a, .dropbtn 
    {
        display: inline-block;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn 
    {
        background-color: ##4CAF50;
    }
    
    li.dropdown 
    {
        display: inline-block;
     position: relative;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content 
    {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #333;
        min-width: 200px;
        box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a 
    {
        color: white;
        padding: 12px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .dropdown-content a:hover 
    {
     background-color: #111
    }
    
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content 
    {
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="Table.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="sponsors.html">Sponsors</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">About</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="entryform.html" class="active">About Busking @ Stanthorpe</a>
      <a href="credits.html">Credits</a>
      <a href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
    <a href="media.html">Media</a>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is your code,, I can see menu, but you had issue with text having white color :)

```css
li a, .dropbtn 
{
    display: inline-block;
    /*color: white;*/
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn 
{
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}

li.dropdown 
{
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content 
{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #333;
    min-width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a 
{
    
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover 
{
    background-color: #111
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content 
{
    display: block;
}
```

```html
 <div id="navbar">
<ul>
        <li><a href="Table.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="sponsors.html">Sponsors</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">About</a>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="entryform.html" class="active">About Busking @ Stanthorpe</a>
      <a href="credits.html">Credits</a>
      <a href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
      <a href="media.html">Media</a>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>   
</div>
```

Comment: Weird, I took the "color: white;" colour out but it still doesn't show up in my browser...

Comment: did you clicked this blue button that said "Run Code snippet", you can see it there for sure

Comment: I know, is there anything I can look for in the rest of my coding?

Answer (score 0):

remove color and try to clear cache and cookies in inspect element > network

```css
li a, .dropbtn 
{
    display: inline-block;
    //color: white; > REMOVE IT 
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: It"s not showing up, but I know it's there. Is there anything else I should look for in the rest of my coding like padding or margins?

Comment: did you already clear cache ? what browser you using it ?, try change color to black in li a, .dropbtn

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    li a, .dropbtn 
    {
        /* color: white; */
        text-align: center;
        padding: 14px 16px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    li {
        display: inline-block;
    }
```